# Why do I get java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet not open. Operation 'next' not permitted. java derby database?

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I'm getting this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet not open. Operation 'next' not
>   permitted. Verify that autocommit is off.

when I'm trying to create instances from a db.

**Current code:**

```
         try
            {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
                stmt = connection.createStatement();
                results = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from animalTable");
                int AnimalCat = -1;
                System.out.print(connection.getAutoCommit());
                //getting error on line below
                while(results.next()) 
                {
                    int ID = results.getInt(1);
                    int Age = results.getInt(2);
                    String Name  = results.getString(3);
                    String AType = results.getString(4);
                    String Breed = results.getString(5);
                    AnimalCat = results.getInt(6);
                    int Adoption = results.getInt(7);
                    String Gender = results.getString(8);
                    String Description = results.getString(9);
                    if(Gender == "Male"){
                        gen = true;
                    }

                    animal = new Animal(Age, AType, gen, Breed, Description, Name);
                    animalList.add(animal);
                    if(AnimalCat != -1){
                        ResultSet resultCat = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from CategoryTable where ID = " + AnimalCat);
                       //without this line below i get a cursor error
                        resultCat.next();
                        System.out.println(resultCat.getInt(1) +"\n\n  " + resultCat.getString(2));
                        String Category = resultCat.getString(2);
                         if(Category == "Lost"){
                           Date input = resultCat.getDate(3);
                           LocalDate date = input.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
                           ResultSet personData = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from PersonTable where ID = " + resultCat.getInt(4));
                           Person person = new Person(personData.getString(2), personData.getString(3), personData.getString(4), personData.getString(5));
                           Category lost = new Lost(date, resultCat.getString(5), person);
                           animal.setAnimalCat(lost);
                           personList.add(person);
                         }
                    }
                }
                results.close();
                stmt.close();  
            }
            catch (SQLException sqlExcept)
            {
                sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I have tried turning off auto commit like it says in the exception and also adding a finally block and closing the statement. From what I can see online that fixed others issues but no luck with mine.

I know the `resultCat.next();` is behind the error somehow but I get an "Invalid cursor state - no current row" without it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `Statement`, obtain a `ResultSet` from the statement, then obtain another `ResultSet`.  This automatically [closes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) the first `ResultSet`:

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement
>   interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an
>   open one exists.

So when you call `next` on the first ResultSet an exception is raised. The Javadoc also tells you what to change: Create a second statement and use that to obtain the second ResultSet.